# What is the best way to store my tent?

Tags: tents, storage

How can I store my tent when I'm not using it for months at a time, so that it is still in good condition when I use it again?

Comment: Heat swings especially hot can cause it to delaminate.

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/15911/11563

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure to thoroughly clean and air it before storing, especially for long periods of time - this will get rid of any damp and thus should help prevent mould. Aside from that, make sure to keep it dry and away from large temperature fluctuations (a loft isn't ideal for this reason.)

Comment: would it help to store it loose? or is it okay to be wrapped tight in it's storage bag?

Comment: @HorusKol As long as it's thoroughly cleaned and aired beforehand then I've never had any problems with mine wrapped tight - and it's often in storage that way for almost a year!

Comment: @berry120 we keep both our tents in the loft and have never had an issue with either.

Answer (score 6):

Best place is to store it in a dry, thermally static environment. Make sure it is well-aired, dry and any muck is removed from it before storing it. Best to check the manufacturers guidelines if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Open it up, sweep it out, let it air dry if it's damp, and pack it up and keep it dry.

Comment: Please explain a bit further. This answer doesn't provide a lot of useful information. It could be useful if you improve it. Otherwise it may be deleted...

Comment: What else to say? There's literally not much that needs to be done, other than to air dry it before you pack it.